# About some property of limit

Tags: real-analysis

In my notes, there are few lines like this：
Let ${x_n}$ be a convergent sequence. Let ${x_{n_k}}$ be a convergent subsequence of $x_n$. Denote  $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} sup{x_{n}}=l$.

Let $\epsilon>0$, by ..., there exist $N\in\Bbb N$ s.t $x_{n_k}<l+\epsilon$, $\forall k\ge N$. Then $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} {x_{n_k}}\le l+\epsilon$. Hence $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} {x_{n_k}}\le l=\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} sup{x_n}$

Why can we just cancel the $\epsilon$? Even though it is arbitrary, $\epsilon$ is always greater than $0$, which means the $\le$ should be changed to $\lt$. But why is it not the case?

Thank you!

Comment: Your misuse of indexes makes the question unclear. What is $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow + \infty} x_{n_{k}}$ ? Do you mean $k \rightarrow \infty$ instead? Do you mean $x_{n_{k}}$ instead of $x_n$ while speaking of the convergent subsequence?

Comment: I have made some editions and should be clear now, please have a look.
Thank you!